# splitting strings in android

Tags: java, android, string

im having a little trouble with splitting a line of text and displaying in a Edittext.

Here is what i have so far.

```
try {
            // open the file for reading
            InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/folder/file.txt");

            // if file the available for reading
            if (instream != null) {
              // prepare the file for reading
              InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
              BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

              String csvRecord;
              while ((csvRecord = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
              String[] csvFields = csvRecord.split(",");
              String display = csvFields[0] + " " + csvFields[3] + "\r\n";

                EditText results = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.results);
                results.setText(toString.display);
                }

            }}
             finally {
            }
```

any help would be great

regards

Answer (score 2):

By using `setText`, you keep resetting the output to the last line. Use either:

```
results.append( display );
```

or

```
StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

while ( ( csvRecord = buffreader.readLine() ) != null )
{
    String[] csvFields = csvRecord.split( "," );
    output.append( csvFields[0] + " " + csvFields[3] + "\n" );
}

EditText results = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.results );
results.setText( output.toString() );
```